# vagrant fails to get machine up. throwing: keep getting an error `prompt': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, centos7

This is the error I am getting:

```
 `prompt': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

It happens sporadically - about 40% of the time.

This is my Vagrantfile (configs variable definition was removed since it contained sensitive info).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "aws-box"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"

  # please note - in aws provider the flag is NOT rsync__exclude but instead rsync_exclude (single underscore, not double)
  # https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/156
  config.vm.synced_folder "../synced_folder", "/vagrant", type: "rsync", rsync_exclude: excludes_array

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: environment_provision_script

  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.path = "../provision.sh"
    s.privileged = false
  end

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.block_device_mapping = [{ 'DeviceName' => '/dev/sda1', 'Ebs.VolumeSize' => 50 }]
    aws.access_key_id = configs['aws']['accessKey']
    aws.secret_access_key = configs['aws']['secretAccessKey']
    aws.keypair_name = configs['aws']['keypairName']

    aws.region = configs['aws']['region']
    aws.instance_type = configs['aws']['instanceType']
    aws.user_data = "#!/bin/bash\nsed -i -e 's/^Defaults.*requiretty/# Defaults requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers"
    aws.ami = configs['aws']['ami']

    aws.tags = {
        'Name' => configs['aws']['machineName']
    }

    override.ssh.username = configs['aws']['ssh']['username']
    override.ssh.private_key_path = configs['aws']['ssh']['privateKeyPath']


  end
end
```

and this is the stack trace

```
11:55:30 ==> default: Launching an instance with the following settings...
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- Type: m3.large
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- AMI: ami-e4ff5c93
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- Region: eu-west-1
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- Keypair: ui-build-centos
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- User Data: yes
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- User Data: #!/bin/bash
11:55:30 ==> default: sed -i -e 's/^Defaults.*requiretty/# Defaults requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- Block Device Mapping: [{"DeviceName"=>"/dev/sda1", "Ebs.VolumeSize"=>50}]
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- Terminate On Shutdown: false
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- Monitoring: false
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- EBS optimized: false
11:55:30 ==> default:  -- Assigning a public IP address in a VPC: false
11:55:35 ==> default: Waiting for instance to become "ready"...
11:56:01 ==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
11:56:55 Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
11:56:55 centos@54.217.146.207's password:==> default: Terminating the instance...
11:56:57 ==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
11:56:57 ==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
11:56:57 /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/prompt.rb:73:in `prompt': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/password.rb:57:in `ask_password'
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/password.rb:22:in `authenticate'
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:79:in `block in authenticate'
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `each'
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `authenticate'
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:211:in `start'
11:56:57    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:355:in `block (2 levels) in connect'
11:56:57    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
11:56:57    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:334:in `block in connect'
11:56:57    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
11:56:57    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:333:in `connect'
11:56:57    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:119:in `ready?'
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.6.0/lib/vagrant-aws/action/run_instance.rb:161:in `block in call'
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.6.0/lib/vagrant-aws/util/timer.rb:9:in `time'
11:56:57    from /var/lib/jenkins/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.6.0/lib/vagrant-aws/action/run_instance.rb:155:in `call'
```

Some background - the vagrant is running as part of an automation that worked flawlessly for a long time (months). Then the following changes occurred:

- We upgraded Vagrant
- We moved to centos
- We added `aws.user_data = "#!/bin/bash\nsed -i -e 's/^Defaults.*requiretty/# Defaults requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers"` to the vagrant file because we got prompts on sudo commands

everything else stayed the same. 
we don't suspect the last item since it should happen long before ssh step.

we cannot figure out why the stacktrace specifies ask_password as we are using a pem file for authentication.

any suggestion or hint as to how to resolve this would be great!

Comment: is this `centos@54.217.146.207's password:==> default: Terminating the instance...` a single line or do you have to type your password ? which version did you move from, seems you're using vagrant-1.6.5 now. hard to say really for sure when thing is not deterministic. can you run with debug `vagrant up --debug` to see if you get any additional useful info

Comment: @FrédéricHenri this generated so much logs, I have no idea what to do with it all.

Comment: I cannot paste the debug prints here. it is 60K character and SO limits to 30K characters.  if any wants I can send it by email. @FrédéricHenri is it ok if I send it to you?

Comment: you can send by mail or you can push on gist or pastebin

Comment: pastebin - great idea - http://pastebin.com/eJKR0Gf0. it will be removed within a week.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri - forgot to mention you in previous comment. the log is at http://pastebin.com/eJKR0Gf0

Comment: it seems it cannot log you in so it wants to default asking a password. can you try to add `override.ssh.insert_key = false` in your Vagrantfile ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri - tried it. gave it a day to run - ran every 30 mins. however no improvement

Comment: @FrédéricHenri - could it be an image issue? should I try changing the image I am using?

Comment: I can't say for sure - the problem is the `It happens sporadically` you could maybe leave debug option for once it runs fine and time it fails so you can compare and might get the root cause of the error